# Struggling with EventEmitter in NodeJS (custom class); used as class Connection extends EventEmitter where EventEmitter is require('events')

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Issues with custom-events inside of a custom-class**

I want there to be a `'ready'` event which I can emit once the class (`Connection`) is "ready".

**Code**

> (I've trimmed most of the code within the class to make it easier):

```js
//Connection.js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Connection extends EventEmitter {
    /**
     * Instansiates the Connection between the REPLIT Database
     * @param connection {String} Connection string URL
     */
    constructor(connection, options) {
        super();
        if (connection) {
            this.connection = connection;
        } else {
            if (!process.env.REPLIT_DB_URL) throw new Error("Please set an env variable REPLIT_DB_URL as the repl's DB URL");
            this.connection = process.env.REPLIT_DB_URL;
        };
        this.emit('ready', connection);
    };
};
```

**Code** (where I use the `.on()`)

```js
const Connection = require('./Connection.js');

const x = new Connection();
x.on('ready', x2 => console.log(x2))
```

And the **error**

```
TypeError: x.on(...) is not a function
    at /home/runner/repldb/index.js:11:1
```

(points to where I use `.on()`)

I've done lots of research and I'm still rather stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: I am using node version 12.6.1

Comment: Did you export the ``Connection`` class?

Comment: Yeah. Everything else with that class works fine, literally just .on doesn't work